# MySQL with Hibernate JPA bad id after commit

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have this code:

```
    EntityManager entityManager = Utilities.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction entityTransaction = null;
    int supplierID = -1;

    try {
        entityTransaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
        entityTransaction.begin();
        entityManager.persist(supplier);
        entityTransaction.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (entityTransaction.isActive())
            entityTransaction.rollback();
    } finally {
        entityManager.close();
        supplierID = supplier.getId();
    }


    return supplierID;
```

The transaction succeeds, because at the end I see my new entry in the table, but supplierID is 0 on return.
What is wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have used the adnotation @GeneratedValue above id in my Supplier class model. Now it updates accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use it correctly, you call the method from the entity Supplier that return the value of the id that is 0. You need to make another query, you can try somethig like this:

```
finally {
    entityTransaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
    entityTransaction.begin();
    Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery("findEmployeeByName");
    supplierID = query.getFirstResult();
    entityTransaction.commit();
    entityManager.close();
}
```

You have an example at [1].

[1] - http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jpa/named-query-with-entity-in-jpa/

Comment: I don't and shouldn't make another query, because it slows the application, and instead the solution in my comment above works without it.